# Make a summary with a mix of roman and arabic numbers

Tags: page-numbering, roman

I'd like to make a table of contents that uses roman numbers for the few pages before said table, and traditional arabic numbers for any pages that follow.

Kinda like shown in here:

[image]

I already have

```
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
```

apologies if this was asked before, didn't immediatly find it.

Comment: Use `book` class, and use `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Alternatively say `\pagenumbering{Roman}` (or `roman` for low case numbers)` before \tableofcontents and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` afterwards

Comment: Mmhm, \pagenumbering doesn't seem to work. \frontmanner managed to do the trick, though my document was originally a report, something I'd have liked to kept that way

Comment: In a normal setup, `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` are not known in `report`

Comment: To generate the table of contents, the page numbers for each chapter etc. are written to the aux (first) and toc (later) using \thepage, so whatever formatting was in effect at the time will be recorded.  You could use \renewdommand\thepage{I don't know} and it would be so recorded in the table of contents.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: The question was not about the display of the page numbers of chapters etc. in the ToC, but just about the numbers on the ToC pages itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard class `report`, `frontmatter` etc. are unknown. Either they are 'stolen' from the their definition in `book.cls` or just `\pagenumbering` is used, as in this example.

```
\documentclass{report}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, I think that did the trick indeed! Thanks a lot!
Though would you happen to know how I can remove the 'chapter 1' part?

Comment: @GillesDV: That's another question

Answer (score 2):

You can define `\frontmatter` etc by yourself inside the `report` class.

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@mainmatter \@mainmattertrue
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \@mainmatterfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}

\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\backmatter


\end{document}
```

[image]

To remove `Chapter 1`, you may employ `titlesec` and put the following in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}
```

But easier is to use the `book` class.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\backmatter


\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that worked wonderfully. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @karlkoeller Thank you friend. :-) I am held up :(